# Logilab compatability with Python 27 windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-import, pylint

I wanted to installed logilab-common 0.61.0 on to my computer I am a windows user and my python version i 27. Whenever I import the module it throws me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import logilab
  File "logilab\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from logilab.common.__pkginfo__ import version as __version__
ImportError: No module named common.__pkginfo__
```

However I checked this file exists. Also when I try to call Pylint (the reason I installed logilab) from command line it throws import error

```
  Loaded Module logilab not not found in sys.modules
```

I also tried to reinstall logilab and logilab astng. I do not If its a compatibility issue perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have two distinct installation of the `logilab` package, one for logilab-common and the other for logilab-astng. Take a look at:

```
import logilab
print logilab.__path__
```

You should fix  things (adjust PYTHONPATH?) so that you get the directory containing the `common` subdirectory there.

Also notice that for recent version of pylint (>= 1.0), logilab-astng has been replaced by `astroid`.